# TypeScriptの構文 (node: NoddeType): node is VNodeが分からない。

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

以下の記事を参考に仮装DOMについて勉強しているのですが、仮想DOMからリアルDOMに反映する箇所のコードの構文がよく分からないです。

`(node: NodeType)`は辞書型アクセスをしているのでしょうか？
ifは省略されているのでしょうか？
`@param`も何を示しているのか分からないです。
`export`とある箇所は後から使用するための関数になるのでしょうか？

[仮想DOMは本当に“速い”のか？ DOM操作の新しい考え方を、フレームワークを実装して理解しよう](https://eh-career.com/engineerhub/entry/2020/02/18/103000)

```
/**
 * Nodeを受け取り、VNodeなのかTextなのかを判定する
 */
const isVNode = (node: NodeType): node is VNode => {
  return typeof node !== 'string' && typeof node !== 'number'
}

/**
 * リアルDOMを作成する
 * @param node 作成するNode
 */
export function createElement(node: NodeType): HTMLElement | Text {
  if (!isVNode(node)) {
    return document.createTextNode(node.toString())
  }

  const el = document.createElement(node.nodeName)
  setAttributes(el, node.attributes)
  node.children.forEach(child => el.appendChild(createElement(child)))

  return el
}

/**
 * 属性を設定する
 * @param target 操作対象のElement
 * @param attributes Elementに追加したい属性のリスト
 */
const setAttributes = (target: HTMLElement, attributes: Attributes): void => {
  for (const attr in attributes) {
    if (isEventAttr(attr)) {
      // onclickなどはイベントリスナーに登録する
      // onclickやoninput、onchangeなどのonを除いたイベント名を取得する
      const eventName = attr.slice(2)
      target.addEventListener(eventName, attributes[attr] as EventListener)
    } else {
      // イベントリスナ−以外はそのまま属性に設定する
      target.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr] as string)
    }
  }
}

/**
 * 受け取った属性がイベントかどうか判定する
 * @param attribute 属性
 */
const isEventAttr = (attribute: string): boolean => {
  // onからはじまる属性名はイベントとして扱う
  return /^on/.test(attribute)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (node: NodeType)は辞書型アクセスをしているのでしょうか？

いいえ。関数の引数です。最初の行はJavaScriptでは `const isVNode = (node) => {` や `function isVNode(node) {` と同等です。

`node is VNode` の部分は関数の戻り値の型を書くところですが、これは [User−Defined Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) で、「この関数が真を返すと、引数 `node` は `VNode` 型である」という型情報をTypescript処理系に伝えます。

> @paramも何を示しているのか分からないです。

[JSDoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) です。

> exportとある箇所は後から使用するための関数になるのでしょうか？

JavaScript module と同じです。

Comment: 詳しくありがとうございます。一度TypeScriptをしっかり勉強したいと思います。